# How to update src of <Image /> tag in NextJS without re-rendering the whole component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-state, react-component, nextjs-image

I want to change the image of a `<Image />` tag in NextJS by updating its `src` with a new link, but it shows too many re-renders.

```
<Image
  src={itemDetails.imageUrls[0].imageUrl}
  alt="Product Image"
  layout="responsive"
  height="500"
  width="400"
/>
```

I want to change this `src` to `{itemDetails.imageUrls[1].imageUrl}` or `{itemDetails.imageUrls[2].imageUrl}` according to onClick on some other images.

I have a function to get the index of `imageUrls`. For example: 0, 1, 2, etc

```
const handleProductClick = (index) => {
  let clickedImageLink = itemDetails.imageUrls[index].imageUrl;
  setImageLink(clickedImageLink);
};
```

Here `setImageLink`is used as a state (useState) and can be accessed using `imageLink`.

But when I substitute `imageLink` like this:

```
<Image
  src={imageLink}
  alt="Product Image"
  layout="responsive"
  height="500"
  width="400"
/>
```

This is how `handleProductClick` is being called:

```
{itemDetails.imageUrls.map((image, index) => {
    return (
       <div className="mr-2 cursor-pointer" key={index}>
       <Image
         src={image.imageUrl}
         alt="Product Image"
         height="80"
         width="70"
         onClick={() => {
         handleProductClick(index);
         }}
        />
       </div>
      );
    })}
```

it shows **Too Many Re-renders error**, like this:

[image]

Comment: Where is `handleProductClick` being called from? Can you please show the full code for the component where the error is happening?

Comment: @AnoopV is there any `useEffect` in the code?

Comment: @ChemiAdel There is no UseEffect, only 1 useState is there

Comment: Why do you need to update src?

Comment: @illiachill I have small version of a few images, when the user clicks on it, the src will be taken and replace the src of a big image, its like toggling between images

Comment: @AnoopV That's still not enough to reproduce the issue. Could you please post the full component's code?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out guys, I figured it out, it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
  const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleProductClick = (index) => {
      setImageIndex(index);
  };
```

And it gets updated like this when clicked on an image:

```
<Image
   src={itemDetails.imageUrls[imageIndex].imageUrl}
   alt="Product Image"
   layout="responsive"
   height="500"
   width="400"
/>
```